# Quickbase: query multiple table to fetch data in single API

Tags: api, record, quickbase

I am looking for body format in quickbase `/records/query` where I can query multiple tables in single API. Right now, I have to use 4 API calls in querying 4 different tables.

Is there any way to do that in single API call?

Answer (score 0):

No, Quickbase's API only supports querying a single table per call.